# top view of 2d function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize a 2d function similar to this: [image: 2d example].

The best way I found is to use [matplotlib.pyplot.contourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf), but for very big functions this is very slow, also the number of levels have to be set before.

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)  # grid of point
Z = fun(X, Y)

levels = np.arange(0, 25)
im = axes.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels, zdir='z', cmap=cm.viridis)
plt.colorbar(im)
```

Is there a 'better' more efficient way of doing this?

The image is from Wikipedia:

[image: wikipedia].

Comment: That's a neat animation.

Comment: What exactly do you want to have: a more efficient contour plot for big amounts of datapoints and levels or this animation of a swarm min-search algorithm? @Mateen Ulhaq definitely, that's nice! :-)

Comment: A more efficient contour plot for big amounts of data points and levels. I only added a static image not confuse people. btw the picture is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization would be great if people also post the code for image generation on Wikipedia